# QGraphicsPixmapItem: No such file or directory ^

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicspixmapitem

I have a problem with Qt. I made some code yesterday and yesterday
everything worked fine, but today i got this message. I reinstalled Qt two times and still got same message on different projects. Someone know how to deal with this?
Here is error that i got from compile output

> C:/Qt/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
>   mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/michal/Documents/build-Game_2-Desktop_Qt_5_6_3_MinGW_32bit-Debug'
>   g++ -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -std=gnu++0x -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_MULTIMEDIA_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN    ../Game_2/tower.cpp   -o ../Game_2/Tower
>   In file included from ../Game_2/tower.cpp:1:0:
>   ../Game_2/tower.h:3:31: fatal error: QGraphicsPixmapItem: No such file or directory
>    #include 
>                                  ^
>   compilation terminated.
>   : recipe for target '../Game_2/Tower' failed
>   mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/michal/Documents/build-Game_2-Desktop_Qt_5_6_3_MinGW_32bit-Debug'
>   makefile:34: recipe for target 'debug' failed
>   mingw32-make[1]: *** [../Game_2/Tower] Error 1
>   mingw32-make: *** [debug] Error 2
>   18:46:16: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
>   Error while building/deploying project Game_2 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.6.3 MinGW 32bit)
>   When executing step "Make"
>   18:46:16: Elapsed time: 00:01.

and code:

```
#ifndef TOWER_H
#define TOWER_H
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QGraphicsPolygonItem>
#include <QGraphicsItem>
class Tower: public QGraphicsPathItem
{
public:
    Tower(QGraphicsItem * parent = 0);
private:
    QGraphicsPolygonItem * attack_area;

};

#endif // TOWER_H
```

https://pastebin.com/u/NoName977

Comment: Did you delete the image you were opening? Moreover, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yeah sorry. I have added code and message from compile output.